# WatchOS 2 Complication with countdown and HkSampleQuery

Tags: ios, swift, watchkit, watchos-2, healthkit

So, I am trying to make a complication for the Apple Watch.
I've got scheduled updates working and can have one that say every half hour refreshes and displays the current time.

What I would like to do is:

A, Use An `HkSampleQuery` call to update with the users most recent steps

B, Have a 'Updated ... Mins ago' line in the complication

For problem A, I can get it to read the steps the first time the complication calls `getCurrentTimelineEntryForComplication`. But afterwards with scheduled updates, code within the `HKSampleQuery` never gets executed. I though that this could be due to no HealthKit calls in background etc... But firstly I think the complication is waked from background when updating, secondly I've seen apps on the store that do the odd think with HealthKit complications, and thirdly, Apple's own activity complication updates fine and that uses HealthKit. Any suggestions there?

For problem B, I can only get the current time at which the complication got updated to be displayed. I would like the complication to update the 'reading from ... Mins ago' field itself abut like the apple timer complication or sunrise/sunset complication ie.sunset in 27mins... Any suggestions there?

Many thanks in advance, hope the question is clear.

Comment: One suggestion (not an answer to your primary question): use HKStatisticsQuery instead of HKSampleQuery.  It's more efficient and will compute the sum for you.

Comment: I'll give that a go, not sure it will run any better when updating from background but will try

Comment: @Allan I am also having issues with using HKSampleQuery during a background refresh in the complication after initial load. Did you ever find anything else out about how to get this to work?

Comment: Nope, sorry. The countdown was fine to implement using the clkrelativedate provider, but no luck with the HKSampleQuery